# How can I express an OR relationship between 2 different lemma-tag pairs of a node in Semgrex?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to extract a node that should either be the verb **live** or the noun **life** using Semgrex. I have tried the following but got a SemgrexParseException for each one:

```
{lemma: live; pos: /VB.*/} | {lemma: life; pos: /NN.*/} 

{lemma: live; pos: /VB.*/ | lemma: life; pos: /NN.*/} 

({lemma: live; pos: /VB.*/}) | ({lemma: life; pos: /NN.*/})
```

What is the correct Semgrex expression for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. You need to surround it with square brackets like so:

```
[{lemma: live; pos: /VB.*/} | {lemma: life; pos: /NN.*/}]
```